# Save file in magento after checkout completation

Tags: magento

I need to save a file after a succesfully checkout. So I'm using the checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after event. When checking out, it stucks if I have some shitty code in there but it goes nicely if I have valid code in the observer. So it gets called, at least I think it does. Can't test it since it doesn't write my file, doesnt write anything in the log etc. So, what could be wrong? Why doesn't it write some stuff into the log? As I said, with other events it works perfectly. It's a new magento installation.

http://pastebin.com/TWyj6CYt cache is disabled. I'm using 1.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you use the following event : **sales_model_service_quote_submit_after**

This event triggers right after the successful creation of an order.

You can also use Mage::log("Observer called"); just to check if your event observer is being invoked.

I hope this helps you :)

Comment: Can i get the data (Ordered Products as well as Shipping Details) there? Thansk to both i'll try it. But i think i tried it with capital letters today, but im not sure. I'll try it again and say if id worked or not :) Thanks and yeha im using the log function. Tried different stuff.

Comment: Yeah both quote and order details will be available in that observer event :) any errors being logged in system.log or exception.log?

Comment: nope, apache either. But i'll take a look at it tomorrow. :) Starting at 0. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a class name `Xxx_saveCheckout_Model_Observer`. Class name parts usually all have uppercase initial letters, the autoloader expects that. Try changing it to `Xxx_SaveCheckout_Model_Observer` (with a capital 'S').

Also make sure the config file has a `/config/global/models` section, although it might be missing from your pastebin on purpose.

Comment: didnt have had  the global, but my other observers work liek that too, so. didnt help. its still not working. :/ hmm a tutorial which works?

Comment: Also... The `etc/modules/Xxx_saveCheckout.xml` file calls the module Xcc_ instead of Xxx_

Comment: yeah thats a mistake happened when canceling the name. x and c is next to each other on my keyboard. :)